# How to set height according to the highest column?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I use tableLayout, and I want to set height of tableRow as tall as it has to be in order to display textViews correctly (which are in linearLayout). At the moment, the second textView is not displayed correctly (it simply doesn't fit in the row).
This is the XML:

```
<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:background="@color/background">

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@color/stripe_background"
        android:gravity="right|center_vertical"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/stripe_padding_buttons_top_bottom"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/stripe_padding_buttons_top_bottom"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/stripe_padding_sides"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/stripe_padding_sides"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/stripe_margin_top_bottom">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/stripe_padding_between_text_views"
            android:gravity="right|center_vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/settings_text_view_current_consumption_main"
                android:id="@+id/textViewCurrentConsumptionMain"
                android:textColor="@color/big_text"
                android:textSize="@dimen/small_text"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/settings_text_view_current_consumption_additional"
                android:id="@+id/textViewCurrentConsumptionAdditional"
                android:textColor="@color/small_text"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/checkBox"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:button="@drawable/check_box_custom"
            android:checked="true" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

In order to make my question clearer, this is the problem in the image. Second textView is not displayed properly:
[image]

Comment: try android:layout_height = "wrap_content" for table row

Comment: @saopayne didn't help.

Comment: try android:layout_weight = "2" and give each textview a layout_weight of 1

Comment: @saopayne that sort of worked, but now the second text view overlaps the first one (but not all of it, just a little bit).

Comment: It might be easier to use a standard checkbox preference and keep things consistent with the Android OS

Comment: @Philio not an option this time, but nice tip though. And, I don't think this is the main issue why height is messed up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make `LinearLayout` and all `TextView`s heights to `wrap_content` (`TableRow`) also